# Cannot install any Python packages using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, paramiko

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/lib'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I'm getting this error when I attempt to install any package, eg `pip install requests`

```
$ pip install requests
Collecting requests
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/47/7e02164a2a3db50ed6d8a6ab1d6d60b69c4c3fdf57a284257925dfc12bda/requests-2.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (91kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 4.8MB/s 
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 143kB 6.1MB/s 
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/df/f7/04fee6ac349e915b82171f8e23cee63644d83663b34c539f7a09aed18f9e/certifi-2018.8.24-py2.py3-none-any.whl (147kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 153kB 7.3MB/s 
Collecting idna<2.8,>=2.5 (from requests)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4b/2a/0276479a4b3caeb8a8c1af2f8e4355746a97fab05a372e4a2c6a6b876165/idna-2.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3<1.24,>=1.21.1 (from requests)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bd/c9/6fdd990019071a4a32a5e7cb78a1d92c53851ef4f56f62a3486e6a7d8ffb/urllib3-1.23-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 143kB 6.7MB/s 
Installing collected packages: chardet, certifi, idna, urllib3, requests
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/lib'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I have completely reinstalled Python 3 via Brew and not sure what else to try. I am running in a virtual environment using `virtualenv`.

## In virtualenv

```
 $ source bin/activate
 $ which python
/Users/matt.canty/virtualenv/sftp-upload/bin/python
 $ which pip
/Users/matt.canty/virtualenv/sftp-upload/bin/pip
 $ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Users/matt.canty/virtualenv/sftp-upload/bin/python-config
```

## Not in virtualenv

```
 $ brew doctor
Your system is ready to brew.
```

Thanks

Comment: try pip install --user requests

Comment: Run `source bin/activate` in the virtualenv directory, then check `which python` again. If that doesn't run, check that `bin/python` still works. Or don't activate and use `bin/pip` directly.

Comment: @VaibhavSharma does not work inside virtual environment.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I caused confusion by trying to avoid it. Apologies I'm a bit tired. Updated the question.

Comment: So what does `which pip` resolve to?

Comment: If it tries to write to ``/lib`` despite the virtualenv being active, it seems to me that it might be a bug. Are you using the latest version of virtualenv as well?

Comment: From my experience, most of the issues of that sort on MacOS result from using brewed Python. Did you brew it? Can you run `brew doctor` and add the output to the question? Also, do you have a `pip.conf` or `.pydistutils.cfg` in your user dir?

Comment: @hoefling I have neither of those files in `~`. Added output of `brew doctor` to question.

Comment: Try installing it with sudo. Either when entering the virutualenv (sudo virtualenv) or when installing it (sudo pip ...)

Comment: Can you run `pip install requests -vvv`? There should be more info available from the log with verbose mode.